# Why Does This Go Under 0

Tags: python

I have a program running which is a part of a 'car racing game' However when the game is supposed to end it doesn't and the remaining race length goes down into the negatives.

I have tried to say only when the remaining race length is above 0 run
and when = to 0 stop but it still continues

```
import random
print("This game is a race where you can select your distance of the race 
and then a dice is rolled")
rounds = 0
while True:
    try:
        race_length = int(input("Choose the Length You Would Like You 
        Race To Be (Between 5 and 15)"))
    except ValueError:
        print("Sorry, I didn't understand that.")
        #if an interger isn't entered do loop above to avoid and error
        continue
    else:
        #race length succesfully found
        #finished the loop
        break
while True:
    try:
         # asking for race length
        car_number = int(input("Choose what number car you would like to 
        be between 0-5"))
    except ValueError:
        print("Sorry, I didn't understand that.")
        #if an interger isn't entered do loop above to avoid and error
        continue
    else:
        #car_number succesfully found
        #finished the loop
        break
 cars= 
[race_length,race_length,race_length,race_length,race_length,race_length]
print(cars[0])
print(cars[1])
while race_length >0:
    chosen = int(random.randint(0,5))
    cars[chosen] = cars[chosen] - 1
    print(cars)
    rounds = rounds + 1
    if cars[1] == 0:
        print("Car Number " + str(chosen) + " Has Finished The Race")
        print(cars)
        print("The race lasted " + str(rounds) + " Rounds")
        if chosen == car_number:
            print("Congratulations, it was your car that finished 
            first!")
        elif chosen != car_number:
            print("Sorry You Did Not Win, Better Luck Next Time")
        break
```

I expect this to finish once 'race_length = 0 in one of the list values however it continues through into the -'s like this:
Car Number 1 Has Finished The Race
[0, 0, -3, 0, -1, -1]
The race lasted 41 Rounds
Sorry You Did Not Win, Better Luck Next Time

Comment: `race_length` is always greater than 0 because you never change it, so your `while` loop never stops.

Comment: even if  i change this to cars[1] it still goes into the negatives any other solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check all elements on list `cars`

```
while cars[0]>0 and cars[1]>0 and cars[2]>0 and cars[3]>0 and cars[4]>0 and cars[5]>0 :
```

---

You can do something similar with `all(list)` which returns `True` if all elements gives `True`. And `0` gives `False`. So when there will be `zero` on list then it gives `False`

```
while all(cars):
```

But negative value also gives `True` so it may gives problem when some element on list  changes value from ie. `1` to `-1` and skips `0`. But I think your code shouldn't have this problem. Or you can use:

```
while all(x>0 for x in cars):
```

Comment: for the third solution when this is no longer true would i be able to put an else: print command in order to state who finish's the race or could i use the same method in checking who has finished the race.

Comment: in python there is construction `while/else` but it doesn't works as in `if/else` and it is useless here. You would have to use `if cars[0] <= 0: print(...) elif cars[1] <= 0: print(...) elif cars[2] <= 0; print(...) ...`

Comment: or `for number, value in enumerate(cars, 1):  if value <= 0:  print(number)` but it gives all cars with value smaller than zero.

Comment: or `winner = min((value, number) for number, value in enumerate(cars, 1)) ; 
print(winner[1])` and it gives one car with the smallest value. But when there are two cars with the smallest value then it will display only one.

Answer (score 0):

You could subtract one from race_length as you go through the loop, and add a message that no car finished the race.